# How to speedup canvas rendering for large number

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to draw ruler scale on canvas, if i draw huge scale with large number then it is taking more than 15s to render entire scale and browser gets struck

Scale Looks like below:
[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cmm =0;
var count = 0
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(200, 0);
for ( i = -33600, j=-336000; i<=46400&& j<=464000; i+=1, j+=10) {
        if (count === 0) { cmm = 0; count++; 
            const scaleVal = i;
          ctx.fillText(scaleVal.toString(), j, cmm+10);
        }
        else if (count === 5) { cmm = 5; count++; }
        else if (count === 9) {cmm = 10; count = 0}
        else { cmm = 10; count++; }
    ctx.moveTo(j , cmm);
ctx.lineTo(j, 15);

}

ctx.stroke(); 

ctx.stroke();
```

```css
.top-div{
height:800px;
widht:800px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#myCanvas{
position:absolute;
top:300px;
}
#parentCanvas {
transform: scale(0.5);
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="top-div">
<canvas id="parentCanvas"  width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="8000" height="15" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

HTML5 canvas would be quite fast. I'm used the above code and I would think it would take less time to render but it is taking long time to render.

It's supposed to draw Ruler Scale. But again, it's taking forever to render and would crash most people's browsers. Any hints as to how to speed this up?

Comment: `Date.now()` is a very very very expensive call, try using the `performance` API instead

Comment: If i see it right your canvas gets rerendered on every loop. Thats what kills it. 
Do you really need a canvas? plain html would probably better for your problem?

Comment: @MaZoli Agree with you, but still my requirement is to optimize canvas rendering..
To draw huge scale in less time with canvas

Comment: Does it help if you draw each individual line as a separate stroke? That way, maybe the lines that are outside the canvas can be culled and don't need to be rasterized. If that doesn't work, you can always cull them yourself, using some basic math to find out which ones are actually visible.

Comment: Also all the `console.log` calls inside the long loop are pretty expensive.

Comment: I just converted your code sample into a code snippet so we can run it.  `for ( i = -33600, j=-336000; i<=46400&& j<=464000; i+=1, j+=10) {` Are you literally drawing this pixel by pixel?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger yes
`for ( i = -3800, j=-1948.5; i<=4200&& j<=2051.5; i+=20, j+=10) {` - this is taking 1ms
`for ( i = -33600, j=-336000; i<=46400&& j<=464000; i+=1, j+=10) {` - this is taking 150ms
how to draw in less time with large numbers

Answer (score 1):

A couple more tricks: you can use window.requestAnimationFrame() to avoid unnecessary re-renders. Also, you may want to ensure that whatever it is you're rendering would actually be on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing values completely off the canvas. Your canvas is only 800x800, but you are drawing things out in the -46400px - 46400px range. What you need to do is 'cull' out all the values that are not within canvas bounding box and only draw values you see. You will need to look at some linear algebra if you would like to support panning, zooming, ect. But the gist is you need to find the bounding rectangle that you see, and only render content within that. This should make your render time around 1ms.

If you need more performance, you can try more complicated techniques such as instancing. Notice how the scale is a repetitive pattern? You can stroke it once, and copy those pixels over and over again offsetting them each time.